# Why MassTransit is sending message to skipped queue and giving timeout exception

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Mass Transit(8.0.6) in .Net core web API, one of the alternate message is always going to skipped queue and failing with timeout exception. 1 request is passing and next is failing.

Exception: at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.d__11.MoveNext() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/ResponseHandlerConnectHandle.cs:line 55
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.d__18`1.MoveNext() in /_/src/MassTransit/Clients/RequestClient.cs:line 195 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at
Consumer Code:

```
{
try
{
var userDetails = new List\<UserDetail\>();
var columns = new List\<ColumnDetails\>() { new ColumnDetails() { ColumnName = "UserId", DataType = typeof(string) } };

                var dataTable = DataTableExtension.CreateDataTable<User>(context.Message.UserIds, columns);
               
                string[] paramName = { "@UserIds", "@FilePath" };
                var data = this._unitOfWork.GetDataFromStoredProcedure("[rabbitmq].[GetUserDetails]", paramName, dataTable, context.Message.FilePath);
                if (data != null && data.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var user = new UserDetail()
                        {
                            UserImage = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["UserImage"]),
                            FullName = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["FullName"]),
                            UserId = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[i]["UserId"])
                        };
                        userDetails.Add(user);
                    }
    
                }
                if (userDetails.Count == 0)
                    await context.RespondAsync<string>("No data found.");
                else
                    await context.RespondAsync<GetUserDetailsResult>(new
                    {
                        UserDetails = userDetails
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

CLient Code:

```
{
private readonly IRequestClient\<GetUserDetails\> \_client1;
private readonly IRequestClient\<GetRecordTokenDetails\> \_client2;
public GetUserAndTokenDetailsRMQHandler(IRequestClient\<GetUserDetails\> client1, IRequestClient\<GetRecordTokenDetails\> client2)
{
this.client1 = client1;
this.client2 = client2;
}
public async Task<GetUserAndTokenDetailsResponse> Handle(GetUserAndTokenDetailsRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
var response = new GetUserAndTokenDetailsResponse() { UserDetails = new List<UserDetail>(), RecordTokenDetailsResult = new List<TokensDetail>() };
try
{
if (request.UserIds?.Count > 0)
{
//2.auth consumer
var result1 = await _client1.GetResponse<GetUserDetailsResult>(new
{
Filepath = request.FilePath,
UserIds = request.UserIds
});

                    foreach (var user in result1.Message.UserDetails)
                    {
                        response.UserDetails.Add(new UserDetail() { FullName = user.FullName, UserImage = user.UserImage, UserId = user.UserId });
                    }
                }
    
                //3.payment consumer
                if (request.RecordTokenDetails != null)
                {
                    var result2 = await _client2.GetResponse<GetRecordTokenDetailsResult>(new
                    {
                        RecordTokenDetails = request.RecordTokenDetails
                    });
                    foreach (var record in result2.Message.RecordTokenDetailsResult)
                    {
                        response.RecordTokenDetailsResult.Add(new TokensDetail()
                        {
                            SharesAvailable = record.SharesAvailable,
                            TotalPendingInvestment = record.TotalPendingInvestment,
                            MyStatusOnRecord = record.MyStatusOnRecord,
                            MyStatusTypeOnRecord = record.MyStatusTypeOnRecord,
                            ArtistId = record.ArtistId,
                            RecordId = record.RecordId,
                            LoggedInUserId = record.LoggedInUserId
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
    
                throw ex;
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Configuration client:

`services.AddMassTransit(config =\> { config.AddConsumer\<GetReleasedCountOfAnArtistConsumer\>(); config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =\> { cfg.Host("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672"); cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("xxx-yyy-queue", c =\> { c.AutoStart = true; c.AutoDelete = true; c.ConfigureConsumer\<GetReleasedCountOfAnArtistConsumer\>(ctx); }); }); config.AddRequestClient\<GetReleasedCountOfAnArtist\>(); });`

Configuration Consumer:

````
{
config.AddConsumer\<GetUserDetailsConsumer\>();
config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =\>
{
cfg.Host("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
cfg.PrefetchCount = 32;
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("xxx-zzz-queue", c =\>
{
c.AutoStart = true;
c.AutoDelete = true;
c.UseMessageRetry(r =\> r.Immediate(5));
c.ConfigureConsumer\<GetUserDetailsConsumer\>(ctx);
});
});
config.AddRequestClient\<GetUserDetails\>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));``your text``
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is the issue but you are expecting a `GetUserDetailsResult` on client code an your consumer code sometimes is returning an `string` instead (on `if (userDetails.Count == 0)` condition)